# How to maintain numerical order in multithreading tasks

Tags: python

I'm scraping a list of URL's using multithreading for faster speeds. For this I'm using `concurrent futures`.

Each URL contains some textual data which is sorted alphabetically on the site. The `map` function randomly chooses URL's and returns data which is unsorted which I don't want in this case because I want to keep the order.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
    
count = 1
def unordered(url):
    global count
    print(f'Page {count}: https://...')
    getitems(url) # actual function to fetch data
    count += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(1,3):
        print('>>> Section -', i)
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            executor.map(unordered, [i for i in range(5)]) # some URL's
        count = 1
```

**Result:**

```py
>>> Section - 1
Page 1: https://...
Page 2: https://...
Page 3: https://...
Page 3: https://...
Page 4: https://...
>>> Section - 2    
Page 1: https://...
Page 2: https://...
Page 3: https://...
Page 3: https://...
Page 4: https://...
```

I just want to print the current page in numerical order like this, so that I'll know which page is currently being processed. What should I do?

```py
Page 1: https://...
Page 2: https://...
Page 3: https://...
Page 4: https://...
Page 5: https://...
```

Comment: Reading the value of `count` and incrementing it aren't thread-safe. Lock first.

Comment: "which page is currently being processed"? There may be more than one at at time because of concurrency.